The column 'Date[Year]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context
I'm going through a Coursera course, and they're asking to add a calculated table based on different columns from other tables (Step 3 in the attached image).
They propose the DAX solution attached, which is giving the mentioned error. All screenshots are added, which include the current model, task instructions, and the provided solution. I do see that there is no relationship between the date table and the Sales table, as there is no common column between the two tables. I'm not sure in the final result how they're getting the year, which I'm assuming from the orderDate column in the sales table and how the Date table is related here.





you have not created the relationship between date table and sales table.

Actually yeah the date and orderDate are the common columns. Not sure why I wasn't seeing that!

Added the relationship between the Date and Sales tables.


is this a solution to your question, or is this an "additional post" to amend your question?
